# RocksDb 7.9.0 library can't open RocksDb 6.2.2 files?

Tags: rocksdb

We've been using RocksDb for years. There's a (.NET) process using RocksDbSharp to generate RocskDb data. There's a C++ library that reads them. Both from 2018 or so. Both use Snappy compression. The C++ library is compiled under C++ 11.

We're trying to upgrade to newer RocksDb now. In unit tests, the new C++ library can create new files and read them just fine. However, it crashes (segmentation fault) on the first `rocksdb::DB::Open` call when accessing the existing data. More specifically, the call stack goes to `LoadTableHandlers`.

Here is the source code, nothing fancy:

```cpp
    rocksdb::DB* db;
    rocksdb::Options options;
    options.compression = rocksdb::CompressionType::kSnappyCompression;
    options.create_if_missing = false;
    rocksdb::Status status = rocksdb::DB::Open(options, myValidPath, &db);
```

See the call stack below.

ZwWaitForSingleObject 0x00007ffff97ad144
WaitForSingleObjectEx 0x00007ffff6ef306e
pthread_join 0x0000000064945edc
_ZNSt6thread4joinEv 0x000000006fce0577
rocksdb::VersionBuilder::Rep::LoadTableHandlers(rocksdb::InternalStats*, int, bool, bool, std::shared_ptr<rocksdb::SliceTransform const> const&, unsigned long long) 0x00000000009747d8
rocksdb::VersionBuilder::LoadTableHandlers(rocksdb::InternalStats*, int, bool, bool, std::shared_ptr<rocksdb::SliceTransform const> const&, unsigned long long) 0x00000000007e86fb
rocksdb::VersionEditHandler::LoadTables(rocksdb::ColumnFamilyData*, bool, bool) 0x00000000007ea471
rocksdb::VersionEditHandler::CheckIterationResult(rocksdb::log::Reader const&, rocksdb::Status*) 0x00000000007ec8c8
rocksdb::VersionEditHandlerBase::Iterate(rocksdb::log::Reader&, rocksdb::Status*) 0x00000000007ebe4c
rocksdb::VersionSet::Recover(std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor, std::allocatorrocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor > const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >*, bool) 0x00000000005bc135
rocksdb::DBImpl::Recover(std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor, std::allocatorrocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor > const&, bool, bool, bool, unsigned long long*, rocksdb::DBImpl::RecoveryContext*) 0x0000000000570caf
rocksdb::DBImpl::Open(rocksdb::DBOptions const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor, std::allocatorrocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor > const&, std::vector<rocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle*, std::allocatorrocksdb::ColumnFamilyHandle* >*, rocksdb::DB**, bool, bool) 0x00000000005698bb
rocksdb::DB::Open(rocksdb::Options const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, rocksdb::DB**) 0x000000000056b88f
main TestMain.cpp:131
__tmainCRTStartup 0x00000000004013c7
mainCRTStartup 0x00000000004014fb
BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007ffff8a174b4
RtlUserThreadStart 0x00007ffff97626a1
 0x0000000000000000

Do we need to tweak something in the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. Calling:

`options.OptimizeForSmallDb();`

before opening eliminates the crash.

Any explanation or analysis from the RocksDb folks?

Answer (score 0):

Shared your question in the Speedb Discord and was asked the following:

"1. Did you try doing that with one of the latest formal versions (e.g., 7.7.3 or 7.7.2)?

2. Did you go over the release notes from 6.2.2 until today? Maybe there's a hint there that would help explain that error."

You can join the discord channel with this [link](https://discord.gg/5fVUUtM2cG)

Follow this [link](https://discordapp.com/channels/1001437353312796782/1044859612018524241) to find the thread about your question

Comment: Thanks. I tried my luck in GitHub, and found a workaround: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/10968. Somehow, `options.OptimizeForSmallDb();` solves the crash.